# How to execute command like "qmake -v > 1.txt" from a specific folder with QProcess?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess, qtcore, qfile

I have a path to a folder and a command to execute from that folder. It's an arbitrary complex command. For ex.: `qmake -v > 1.txt`.

I figure I need to run a shell (cmd.exe because I'm on Windows atm.), and execute the command there:

```
QProcess::startDetached("cmd.exe", QString("qmake -v > 1.txt").split(' ',
```

QString::SkipEmptyParts), "C:/folder/");

But it doesn't work. It does launch a console window (cmd.exe) at the specified path, but doesn't execute the command. Then I've tried:

```
QProcess::startDetached("cmd.exe", QStringList() << "start" << QString("qmake -v > 1.txt").split(' ', QString::SkipEmptyParts), "C:/folder/");
```

Also no luck. And finally, just to test if I'm going anywhere with this at all:

```
QProcess::startDetached("qmake.exe", QString("-r -tp vc").split(' ', QString::SkipEmptyParts), "C:/folder_containing_qt_project/");
```

A console window appears for a brief moment, but project is not generated.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I achieve what I want with `QProcess` (I don't mind using WinAPI if there's no other way, but strongly prefer to use the same code on Linux / Mac OS X / Windows)?

It might be worth noting that in another method of the same app I have no problem executing `notepad.exe <path to a text file>` with `startDetached`.

Comment: Did you try to run: `QProcess::startDetached("qmake.exe -r -tp vc", QStringList(), "C:\\folder_containing_qt_project")`?

Comment: @vahancho: just tried. `startDetached` returned `false`.

Comment: What do you mean by not executing the command? How do you know it does not? Also, any reason for not reading the output in and write it out with QFile?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I know it because the command has clearly visible side effects, which are absent.

Comment: It is possible that it runs the command, but there is some error, hence asking. You need to make sure what actually is going on. Also, qmake.exe will not be portable, inherently. You may wish to drop the .exe suffix.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: yes I do, but no ways of debugging this issue come to mind. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this method:

> [void QProcess::setStandardOutputFile(const QString & fileName, OpenMode mode = Truncate)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#setStandardOutputFile)

You would be using it then like this:

```
QProcess myProcess;
myProcess.setStandardOutputFile("1.txt");
myProcess.start("qmake -v");
myProcess.waitForFinished();
```

You could also read the output into the application and write that out with QFile. This may get you going into that direction:

> [QByteArray QProcess::readAllStandardOutput()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput)
>
> Regardless of the current read channel, this function returns all data available from the standard output of the process as a QByteArray.

Therefore, you could write something like this, but it is a bit more complicated, and potentially memory-hungry, so it is just for demonstratation purposes without chunk read and write.

```
QProcess myProcess;
myProcess.start("qmake -v");
myProcess.waitForFinished();
QFile file("1.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
file.write(myProcess.readAllStandardOutput());
file.close();
```

Disclaimer: I intentionally did not write error checking to keep it simple.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess I'll have to parse `>` symbol and use `setStandardOutputFile` if neccessary. Thanks.

Comment: What are the pros of using `QFile` + `readAllStandardOutput` as opposed to `setStandardOutputFile`? The latter is way easier to implement, especially in my case where redirection may or may not be needed.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: edited my answer. I also prefer setStandardOutputFile since that hides the boilerplate of manual writing.

Comment: It seems like `setWorkingDirectory(absluteDirPath)` has no effect. Have you ever encountered this problem?;